# Как найти информацию в строке по ID?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Я совсем новичок в mysql и php, и у меня возникла с выводом данных в моей таблице.
Допустим, у меня уже есть готовая таблица buyorders вида:

order_id order_desc order_amount

1 покупка тестового товара 1999

order_id - id моего заказа, order_desc - описание заказа, order_amount - цена заказа.
Как найти по id заказа строку, и занести order_desc в $description, а order_amount в $amount?

Пробовал вариант:

```
<?php
$order_id;
$order_desc;
$order_amount;

$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','пароль','orders');

if(isset($_GET["id"])){
  
    $order_id = $_GET["id"];
}

$result = $connect->query("SELECT `order_amount` FROM `buyorders` WHERE `order_id` = '{$order_id}'");
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $result;
```

id в данном случае берется из поисковой строки, и вносится в переменную, но данный метод не работает! Выдаёт следующую ошибку

Array to string conversion in /var/www/сайт.site/pay/test.php on line 18
Array

Comment: и почему бы не перевести вам эту ошибку?

Comment: что возвращает mysqli_fetch_array?

Comment: Возвращает Array

Comment: Отлично. А теперь подскажите, работает ли echo с массивами? Или для этого нужен другой метод, функция?

Comment: Дело в том, что echo я использую здесь только для проверки. В дальнейшем мне число или текст надо вывести в html. Так что про echo или не echo тут вообще не принципиально.

Comment: Мне нужно вывести число в переменную. А как это сделать - я не знаю.

Comment: "Так что про echo или не echo тут вообще не принципиально" --- нет принципиально. Вы же пишите что "данный метод не работает! Выдаёт следующую ошибку

Array to string conversion in /var/www/сайт.site/pay/test.php on line 18 Array"   значит важно.........."Мне нужно вывести число в переменную" --- вы же знаете как работать с массивами? Или ещё нет?

Comment: Нет, не знаю. Но в интернете нет решения моего вопроса. Захожу я значит в учебник по php https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-keys.php, и как это использовать мне не понятно. Мне нужно получить ЦИФРУ, не палочки и символы. Эту цифру я хочу вывести в html благодаря <p><?php $order_amount ?></p>

Comment: В интернете есть книга "Котеров - PHP 7 в подлиннике", а также php для новичков. Может быть вначале ознакомитесь с базой языка, прежде чем писать сами не знама что?

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но сюда я пришел не чтобы многотонные сборники читать.

Comment: Ужас, что вы говорите)) Хорошо, что нет подобных ресурсов для хирургов или стоматологов, а то стало бы совсем страшно жить :D

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а вдруг есть?

Comment: А автору вопроса стоит подумать над тем что если `echo` работает со строками, а строка это не массив, то может и не стоит тогда использовать `echo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysqli_fetch_array() возвращает массив в котором каждый элемент это строка из базы данных и является массивом колонок из это строки, где ключ массива это имя колонки указанной в SELECT запроса, а значение - значение этой колонки.

Поэтому можно сделать так:

```
<?php
$order_id;
$order_desc;
$order_amount;

$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','пароль','orders');

if(isset($_GET["id"])){
  
    $order_id = $_GET["id"];
}

$result = $connect->query("SELECT `order_amount`, `order_desc`, FROM `buyorders` 
WHERE `order_id` = '{$order_id}'");
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$order_desc = $result[0]['order_desc'];
$order_amount = $result[0]['order_amount'];
echo $result;
```